# Unable to connect to webservice using Chrome Advanced REST Client but able to connect through chrome browser

Tags: resttemplate, advanced-rest-client

I need to connect to a third party webservice. When I hit the link directly in the chrome browser, I am able to connect to it and I get a response. But when I tried the same using Advanced REST Client app of chrome, I get a message as 'The service's server DNS address could not be found.'

Also, when I tried to connect it via my JAVA code, using spring's rest template, am getting an Unknown host exception. What could be the reason that am able to connect via browser but not otherwise?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a problem with your system's DNS settings? I'm not sure how Chrome handles queries to DNS when primary DNS did not found the record. If it uses Google DNS' then Chrome may connect to the service but other applications can't. 
To test it set your DNS to 8.8.8.8 and check if apps start working.

Answer (score 0):

From browser it's working properly but not from rest client or application, then i guess the problem with the proxy.
if you are using your office network, then this issue will come.

Try hitting the webservice by connecting to personal network.

i have faced similar issue last week, from browser and postman i'm able to hit the web service but not from the application.

Ones i connected with my personal then it started working.

Hope it helps.